Mapbox Pitch Value sometimes wrong on reload
I am using Mapbox on this site here rebgut.gloeggl.dev (in the footer). And sometimes on reload the pitch value is wrong. Does anybody know why this could be?
Tried out everything it seems but it's still messed up sometimes.
Because of the way I use the map in the footer the correct pitch is really important.
Would appreciate any help!
Thank you!
Stefan
Tried out adding window.onload on the whole script.

Where's the page with the map?
Anyways, did you set the hash option to true?
